# Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns

Tags: mysql, sql, truncate

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE jobroles ( 
    jobrole_id VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    jobrole VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL, 
    jobrole_description VARCHAR(10000) NOT NULL
);
```

I am loading my data using this command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/harrylevick/Documents/GitHub/jobtech-occupation-selector/data/jobroles.csv' INTO TABLE jobroles FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

and here is row 1:

```
jobrole_id,jobrole,jobrole_description
c785f4fefed56cc5bcd09ba5728e38323438814508d4c888d6a27e4647b7bc15,1st Assistant Cameraman/Focus Puller* (Specialty Camera Operation),"The 1st Assistant Cameraman/Focus Puller supports the shooting operations for various types of camera equipment including specialty cameras. He/She is responsible for maintaining focus between the lens and subjects. He does this by setting up a complex set of indicators placed on the set floor or props during rehearsal. He collaborates with various production teams to ensure a consistent focus during the shoot. In addition to focus pulling for the camera operator he manages and maintains the camera equipment such as lenses filters and camera boxes for assembling the camera and its accessories for different shots. Before shooting he arrives on the set early to ensure that the camera and all the required lenses are prepared for a day's shoot. At the end of each day he resolves the problems with the 'rushes' and liaises with the film lab to rectify any faults with the camera or film stock. He then proceeds to clean the equipment and pack it up in preparation for the next day's shoot. He may also be required to set up and mount specialty camera equipment and assist in the operation of specialty cameras such as 360 cameras underwater cameras and aerial cameras during the shoot.The work involves physically demanding tasks especially the capture of motion sequences amidst high pressure. He is expected to operate in an outdoors environment and may be required to travel depending on the location of the shoot. He needs to have strong knowledge of camera equipment a strong affinity with technology knowledge of the relevant electronics and an in-depth knowledge of the principles of camera work. He is required to be an effective team player and shows diplomacy and sensitivity when working with artists production staff and crew. He should have good colour vision and excellent hand-eye co-ordination."
```

I really have no Idea why its truncated since I have used the OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' command to catch any extra commas in the text.

Comment: but you also specified ENCLOSED BY '"'

Comment: What column's value was truncated really? what is its final value?

Answer (score 0):

ENCLOSED BY '"' means that you should enclode your columns in "

Taken from mysql docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

> If the input values are not necessarily enclosed within quotation
> marks, use OPTIONALLY before the ENCLOSED BY option.

Comment: I have edited my post with the updated command that still truncates the first row

Comment: If you work on windows you can put also LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

Comment: Also put the FIELDS .. TERMINATED BY clause before the ENCLOSED BY clause